# Rails: Having issues accepting multiple products for my order

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I seem to be having some issues with accepts multiple products through my dynamic form, I followed a railscast guide, and edited it slightly for my own system. But I am getting an error now, I've listd everything on a gist for ease of viewing:

[Gist on github](https://gist.github.com/mccabec123/5564745)

The gist also includes the error message I am receiving, it seems to be due to the fact that the order ID is not present, but other than that I can't seem to pinpoint the error.

This is the railscast guide that I followed: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Comment: The code you posted as OrderedProductsModel is actually the Order model. Where's your OrderedProducts model? Also, you seem to have added the Product with id 1 to the new Order. Does that product exist?

Comment: Okay I updated the gist, sorry about that. Yes that product does exist, it's coming from the products table.

Comment: Are you sure you want to create products this way?  Often, it's the line items you want to create, and the line_item (or ordered_product) would have a product_id.  Products usually already exist.